# Getting all permutations for weightings according to an interval

Tags: c#, arrays, permutation, combinations, combinatorics

If I have a  given number of 'systems'

```
var nbSystems = 2;
```

and a number of 'steps'

```
var nbSteps = 3;
```

How can I generate all the following permutations :

```
{0.00, 0.00}
{0.33, 0.00}
{0.67, 0.00}
{1.00, 0.00}
{0.00, 0.33}
{0.33, 0.33}
{0.67, 0.33}
{1.00, 0.33}
{0.00, 0.66}
{0.33, 0.66}
{0.67, 0.66}
{1.00, 0.66}
{0.00, 1.00}
{0.33, 1.00}
{0.67, 1.00}
{1.00, 1.00}
```

I need a weight between 0 to 1 for each system and I want to find all permutations.

You see that the interval to use for the systems weights is calculated from the nbSteps (interval = 1 / nbSteps).

I would like to have a function that takes inputs nbSystems and nbSteps (or better?) and that will output some sort of multidimensional array with all the permutations...

Comment: nbSystems is the number of dimensions of the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nbSystems = 2;
    var nbSteps = 3;

    var steps = GetSteps(0, 1, nbSteps).Select(n => Math.Round(n, 2)).ToArray();
    foreach (var seq in GetCombinations(steps, nbSystems))
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", seq));
}

private static IEnumerable<decimal> GetSteps(decimal min, decimal max, int count)
{
    var increment = (max - min) / count;
    return Enumerable.Range(0, count + 1).Select(n => min + increment * n);
}

private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetCombinations<T>(
    ICollection<T> choices, int length)
{
    if (length == 0)
    {
        yield return new T[0];
        yield break;
    }

    foreach (var choice in choices)
        foreach (var suffix in GetCombinations(choices, length - 1))
            yield return Enumerable.Concat(new[] { choice }, suffix);
}
```

Adjust as necessary if you care about the order of the combinations.

EDIT:  Oops, fixed a typo - I transposed "max" and "min" in my type signature.

Comment: Looking good, amazing! I'll test it more and it should be the accepted answer soon. Thanks again :)

Comment: This does not output an array, it only outputs console lines.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
double nbSteps = 3.0;

IEnumerable<double> SystemA = Enumerable.Range (0, (int)nbSteps).Select (x => x / nbSteps); 
IEnumerable<double> SystemB = Enumerable.Range (0, (int)nbSteps).Select (x => x / nbSteps); 

var Result = from a in SystemA from b in SystemB select new { a, b };
```

Comment: +1 for learning, that looks interesting! is it possible to make it more generic to accept any number of sytems? :)

Comment: Where did you get the int,double method signature for Range? I may have just missed it but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx for the int version... corrected my code a little... thanks